# Gamma Distribution in Apache beam using python

Tags: apache-beam

I want to implement gamma distribution function in Apache beam using Python. Check the link below to get an idea about Gamma Distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

I have the code which is implemented in python, the same I'm trying in Apache beam using Pcollections.

Any kind of help or lead will be highly appreciated.

Python code for gamma distribution :

> from scipy.stats import gamma
>   import numpy as np
>   shape, scale = 2. , 2.
>   rv = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)
>   print(rv)

Comment: for the above python code the output is :                                                        
[ 1.87845653  4.06561188  1.80081615 ...,  2.53946377  1.97664771
  2.47229177]

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you'd like to create a PCollection containing an extremely large number (how many - thousands, millions, trillions?) of Gamma-distributed values with the same shape and scale parameter, in order to process them in parallel with some other computation using Beam?

Comment: Gamma distribution is calculated using the formula : GammaDist(x, alpha, beta, cumulative), x is the value at which you want to evaluate the distribution. Its just I want to create a DoFn in which gamma distribution will be calculated and I want to do this implementation using sciPy library. How to do that ??

Comment: DoFn's are just regular Python code, you can invoke libraries from them, including scipy. Have you tried doing that but run into runtime errors? Can you share the Beam code you have so far?

Comment: That is what . How to do that ?? I haven't developed the code till now, Nowhere I have seen any code sample to get an idea of how to do that. And this is what I'm continuously asking **Please provide me a code sample which demonstrate numpy/scipy in apache beam**

Comment: If you have a PCollection "foo" of numbers (say: 2 3 4), then "foo | beam.FlatMap(np.arange)" will give you a PCollection whose contents is the joined np.arange() of each of these numbers - this case, it'll be 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 (not in this order).

Comment: @jkff : Thanks buddy !! Now I have the idea and I can move ahead and I really appreciate your time and efforts. :)

Comment: @jkff : In the above example, If PCollection "foo" of numbers (say: 2 3 4) is replaced with a pcollection :  inp1 = p | 'readFile1' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://tegclorox/Input/FBasis11.csv') ....hen how shall i perform operation similar to beam.FlatMap(np.arange).

Comment: Is your question about how to parse a PCollection of strings (lines of the CSV file) into numbers? I suggest to post a separate question about that, with more details of what your format looks like.